# Very simple image slider to auto slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Hey guys I have an image slider that has controls but I also want to intergrate an auto scroll into the JS too. I have looked around but cannot seem to understand where to insert the code I need and exact what code it is..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
    $('.sp').hide();    
    $('.active').show();

    $('#button-next').click(function() {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');

        if ( $('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
            $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
        }
        else {
            $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }

        $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
        $('.sp').fadeOut();
        $('.active').fadeIn();
    });

    $('#button-previous').click(function() {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
        if ( $('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
            $('.sp').last().addClass('active');
        }
        else {
            $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
        }
        $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
        $('.sp').fadeOut();
        $('.active').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

So it has literally a next and previous nav which works fine I would like it to just auto scroll through the images.

Comment: By scroll do you mean a slideshow?

Comment: Yes exactly that, a slideshow but automatically slide through the images :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create 2 new buttons `Start` and `stop`. It's up to you if you want to style them to hide one and show the other. Here's a sample code

```
var slideshow;

$('#start').click(function(){
    slideshow = setInterval(function(){
        $('#button-next').click();
    }, 1000);
});

$('#stop').click(function(){
    clearInterval(slideshow);
});
```

I just wrote this so there may be some issues, in which case be sure to leave a comment! `:P`

**EDIT**

Here's for automatic start

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#button-next').click();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Does it require buttons? Is there no way I can jus enable the slideshow to begin automatically?

Comment: Well if you don't want to stop it

Comment: So the code you put together for automatic start replaces all the code I submitted?

Comment: Noo, just add it at the bottom of yours, inside the document ready function